# Search in Dokument using AppsScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for a way to search a document for the current date using AppsScript. The data are divided into multiple segments, for example A6: HK6 and A76: HK76 ...  As soon as the date has been found, the cell should be set to Active so that it can be linked with a button or something similar to always find the current date.

Comment: I might consider using textfinder and using the string version of the date

Answer (score 0):

I searched for it with a `TextFinder`, saved the current date in a variable and then set a `setActiveSelection`.

```
function jumpToMonth() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();


  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "dd.MM.yyyy");
  var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder(date);

  var ranges = textFinder.findAll();
   Logger.log(date);

  Logger.log('ranges.length = ' + ranges.length);

  for ( var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++ ) {

      Logger.log('A1Notation = ' + ranges[i].getA1Notation()) ;
      sheet.setActiveSelection(ranges[i].getA1Notation());

  }
}
```